# Inspecting AngularJS scopes using the Batarang Chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, batarang

I have an question about AngularJs scopes and especially the way those can be inspected with the Batarang Chrome extension.

I have the following **html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div enhanced-textarea ng-model="name"></div>
     <div cmp>
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <div notice></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the **directives**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('cmp', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'cmpCtrl',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                name: '='
            },
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
    .controller('cmpCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs' , function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$parent.$watch('name', function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $scope.$parent.updatedSize = newVal.length;
            }
        }, true);
    }])
    .directive('enhancedTextarea', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: '<textarea ng-transclude></textarea>'
        };
    })
    .directive('notice', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^cmp',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                updatedSize: '='
            },
            template: '<div>{{size}}</div>',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, cmpCtrl) {
                $scope.$parent.$watch('updatedSize', function (newVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        $scope.size = newVal;
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        };
    });
```

and the **controller**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'test';
  }]);
```

When I inspect the scopes using batarang, **I come up with the following conclusion**:

- Scope 002: ng-app
- Scope 003: ng-controller (myCtrl)
- Scope 004: **????**
- Scope 005: cmpCtrl (controller for cmp directive)
- Scope 006: inside cmp (h3 and notice)
- Scope 007: link function of notice directive

  1. **Is the above correct?**
  2. Also, my biggest interrogation is **what does the 004 scope correspond to?**

Full app is located on github [here](https://github.com/balteo/angularjs-directives/tree/v1.0/app)

See also screen capture below:

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that each `$scope` has to correspond to an element of your page. In fact in every AngularJS app there are a bunch of `$scopes` which aren't directly linked to any element.

In your case it's the `ng-transclude` which causes a child scope to be created.

Take a look at the implementation of AngularJS which causes the creation of your `004` `$scope`.

```
if (!transcludedScope) {
    transcludedScope = scope.$new();
    transcludedScope.$$transcluded = true;
    scopeCreated = true;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L959

If you like to dig deeper yourself, go and set a breakpoint right here in your AngularJS file:

[image]

Then just use the call stack and follow the rabbit...

Answer (score 2):

I also use this scenario to debug and inspect what is in the scope of an element, might be helpful:

- You inspect the element with chrome dev tools
- Once you select certain element you can get its scope by typing in console:

`angular.element($0).scope()`

- You can get the controller in the same way just instead of scope() you can type controller()
- In order to set a breakpoint in you code and look at in in chrome debugger (I sometimes find this easier than setting a breakpoint in dev tools) you can type:

`debugger;`

in your source and dev tool will stop there so you see the declared vars etc.